# Hibernate QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Как можно из таблицы которая не мепится вытащить значения? Есть таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нее автоматически записываются значения, из двух ентити связанных связью ManyToMany. Я хочу теперь получить значения из этой таблицы записывая в DAO следующий запрос:

```
@Override
public List<Menu> getAllFromPlace(Long id){
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Long> ids = em.createQuery("SELECT menu_id  FROM place_has_menu WHERE place_id="+id).getResultList();
List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<Menu>();
for(Long idd : ids){
    menus.add(getById(idd));
}
return menus;
```

}

Но возвращает ошибку:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/caferacer] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: m near line 1, column 16 [SELECT menu_id m FROM place_has_menu phm WHERE place_id=6]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: m near line 1, column 16 [SELECT menu_id m FROM place_has_menu phm WHERE place_id=6]] with root cause org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: m near line 1, column 16 [SELECT menu_id m FROM place_has_menu phm WHERE place_id=6]

И это как бы логично, потому что, запрос нужно писать не SQL, а HQL, но как написать такой запрос или каким образом можно вытащить значения из этой таблицы если у меня нету класса ентити, который бы ее меппил.

Update 1: 
Нашел ответ на этот вопрос и возможно он кому-то также пригодится.
Ответ, который маркирован как правильный, он так же подходит для решения этой задачи, но этот вариант есть небезопасным так как в момент выполнения программы, вы можете получить синтаксическую ошибку, которую тяжело определить на этапе компиляции. С выходом в 2009м году JPA 2.0, появился интерфейс Criteria, который собственно и решает проблему типобезопасных запросов. 
Почитать более подробно о самом интерфейсе Вы можете здесь:[Динамические типобезопасные запросы в JPA 2.0](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-typesafejpa/)!
Ознакомившись с данным материалом, вы увидите, что Вам нужно настроить автогенерацию метамоделей, но не у всех документациях указаны нюансы JPA касательно генерации в IDE Eclipse. 
Сделав все как указано в [доках](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html/), если вы используете Eclipse, сделайте следующие действия Project-Properties-Jpa. Внизу скрина вы увидите, что нужно указать source folder куда будут помещаться генерируемые модели.
После этого, посмотрев любой пример, Вы быстро поймете, как писать типобезопасные запросы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate располагает возможностью написания нативного SQL. Приведу вам пример :

```
String SQL = ".."; //Запрос, который Вас интересует
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(SQL); //Не требует маппинга
query.setParameter("какой-то параметр", 123);
```

И далее можно использовать

```
query.getResultList();
query.getSingleResult();
```

Если нужно более подробное ознакомление предлагаю ссылки : 
[Ссылка на документацию](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)
[Ссылка на Query class](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html)

Comment: а как параметр задавать? стрингом? и это должна быть переменная поля в классе, ведь мне нужно вытащить значения, которые не маппит гибернейт.

Comment: я делал как раз по этим документациям, что вы скинули, но там есть много невнятных нюансов. а что делает метод .setParameter()? что он сеттает?

Comment: спасибо, ваш ответ работает. только я сеттер этот не использовал просто. не понимаю, для чего он нужен.

Comment: Допустим есть такой sql -> "select * from user where name = ?".Здесь как раз и будем применять q.setParameter(0, "Ivan"). 0 - это позиция. Или как у меня в ответе выше по наименованию.  sql =  "select * from user where owner = :name ". query.setParameter("name", "Ivan");

Comment: Исправил ссылку на query, используем конечно же из jBoss документации.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/query_native.html Хочу еще добавить эту ссылку, тут объясняется мой пример, который я привел.

Comment: я обновил вопрос и дописал его решения с помочь интерфейса Criteria.